# How to Access Properties Using Metro Modern UI

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am attempting to use Metro Modern UI in a Windows Forms application but I’m unable to override the default colors. The MetroToggle background color doesn't update the slider portion but behind the caption. I'm also not able to update the text property at all. How am I able to access these properties and change them?

Using the `.Text = "string"` has resulted in no change. When in debug at the line that the text property is changed something is overriding my code and changing it to either "On" or "Off" respectively.

```
private void metroToggle2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    metroToggle2.Text = (metroToggle2.Checked) ? "Started" : "Stopped";
}
```

Where are the properties for this control being generated so that I can change them?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it without code in properties tab or with code like:

```
metroTextBox1.UseCustomForeColor = true;
```

[image: UseCustom]

Comment: Those properties are currently set to true and Windows is ignoring it somehow.